# $_SESSION vars created outside of Drupal lost when navigating to a Drupal served page

Tags: 7, sessions

I'm building a **Facebook iframe app** in Drupal.

I'm using an initial simple PHP script (non-Drupal driven) to handle the Facebook open auth side of things - this script is getting the Facebook user's name, id, profile pic etc.
This script stores those values to session vars. Then it redirects the user to a page served by Drupal.

My understanding looking at the D7 `session.inc` is that pre-existing session vars should be maintained when Drupal session start is called. But if I `print_r()` the `$_SESSION` array, it is empty.

So essentially a plain PHP script saying:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = 'bob';
```

sets the session correctly.
But when then adding a redirect (`header()`) to a Drupal served page I can no longer get that name variable and the session is empty.

Any suggestions/tips?

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: I believe you need to bootstrap Drupal in your custom PHP file using code such as `require_once 'path/to/drupal/includes/bootstrap.inc';  drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION);`. That should give you the correct session

Comment: Why don't you use the correct module for Facebook integration? For example like [Drupal for Facebook](http://drupal.org/project/fb).

Answer (score 4):

A really good source related to your question from drupal.org's forum:
**[Struggling with Session Variables (the `$_SESSION` array) when redirecting to external php scripts](http://drupal.org/node/575002)**

The key for codes outside Drupal's full control to work is to save PHP's current working directory, change it to Drupal's, requiring the needed file to bootstrap Drupal ([`includes/bootstrap.inc`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/7)), pass the appropriate [`$cookie_domain`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/cookie_domain/7) variable (*"the domain to be used for session cookies"*!), bootstrapping Drupal, and then change the current working directory back to the original. After this, you can write your own codes and use Drupal's functions, mess with its session variables, etc. - of course, depending on the bootstrapping mode of Drupal.

The code to achieve it looks like this (you have to change `$your_drupal_directory` variable to yours, usually this is in the root, but its path can be different [e.g. if it's in a subdirectory]):

```php
// ...

/**
 * @see http://drupal.org/node/575002
 */

// store current working directory
$currdir=getcwd();
// which is your Drupal directory? (usually it's in the root, but can be different)
$your_drupal_directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
// change PHP's current directory to Drupal's
chdir($your_drupal_directory);
// including bootstrap file...
require_once("./includes/bootstrap.inc");

// The domain to be used for session cookies. (see: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/cookie_domain/7)
$cookie_domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

// DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION: initialize session handling.
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION);

// the code above should be enough for your task, but if you want Drupal to be "fully loaded, validate and fix input data", you could try the following too (see: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_bootstrap/7)
// drupal_bootstrap( DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL );

// change PHP's current directory BACK to the original
chdir($currdir);

// ...
// YOUR OWN CODE COMES HERE
// ...
```