# How do I access Session variables in Drupal that were set on non-drupal pages?

Tags: theming, sessions, configuration, cookies

If I go `print_r($_SESSION)` on a drupal page (say `mysite.com/` )I only get `Session variables` set from drupal pages (which are none atm). I can set new ones and they'll show up.

```
Array
(

)
```

However If I `print_r($_SESSION)` on a non-drupal page (say `mysite.com/somefolder/index.php`) on the same domain I get a different (and desired) array:

```
Array
(
    [last_url] => /downloads/full.php
    [ip] => ::1
    [address1] => 
    [address2] => Australia
    [zip] => 
    [phone] => 
    [fax] => 
    [dealer] => 
    [referral] => 
    [software] => 
    [searchTerms] => 
    [user_type] => user
)
```

I have `session_start();` at the beginning of all files.

How does my site seemingly have two `$_SESSION arrays`? How can I access my `$_SESSION` vars set on non-drupal scripts within drupal pages?

Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is that you need to tell your external script to use Drupal $_SESSION variable. So you need to use the "drupal_session_start" instead of "session_start". For this, you need to include Drupal bootstrap in your external script.

This post looks like it answers your needs: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26827/session-vars-created-outside-of-drupal-lost-when-navigating-to-a-drupal-served

Answer (score 1):

You also need to boostrap drupal before use drupal's sessions (here: [Properly bootstrap drupal for standalone PHP file?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28511/properly-bootstrap-drupal-for-standalone-php-file))